# A word or idiom to describe an abusive parent who wants to keep their child

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idiom-requests

I just finished watching the video game *[Among the Sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Among_the_Sleep)* and at the end

> (SPOILER ALERT) the mother is the abusive one.

At the beginning of the game, the mother seems to cling onto the child possibly in memory of the little boy's father. At the end though, the father comes and takes care of the baby. I want a word or idiom to describe how the mother is attached to the baby—maybe as a way to get to the father—but who doesn't show any real love to the infant.

[image]

Comment: "I want a word …" Not everything can be captured in a single word—unless perhaps you are into germanic-style hyphenating. Sometimes it's better to look at a pithy way to capture a concept in words.

Comment: It sounds like the mother is psychopathic.

Comment: Overprotective -- doing more harm than good.

Comment: Munchausen's syndrome by proxy?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munchausen_syndrome_by_proxy.

Comment: Brad is entirely correct medically speaking. However, you might be asking for something colloquial.

Comment: And what kind of sick bastard comes up with such a video game? Can I say that here?

Comment: @StuW Why does it make someone a 'sick bastard' to create a video game with dark themes?

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you're looking for is '**proxy possessiveness**' . We could possibly say, the mother is clinging on to the father through the child. Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

The word **possessive** is typically applied to a person who, from a desire for control, rather than from true affection or love, attempts to assert ownership or dominance over another person.

> **possessive**:
>   - wanting all of someone's attention and love
>   - manifesting possession or the desire to own or dominate
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/possessive

Answer (score 0):

How about **vengeful** of **spiteful**?

OD:

> [**vengeful**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vengeful):
>   seeking to harm someone in return for a perceived injury
>
> [**spiteful**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spiteful):
>   showing or caused by malice